# exchangelib consistently returns 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'iterator' when using chunkify

Tags: exchangelib

**Problem**:
When using exchangelib for large amounts of emails(in this case 10K+) the entire set is attempted to be loaded.  I have tried to employ chunkify:

```py
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account

for item in account.inbox\
        .filter(is_read=False, sender__contains='gmail')\
        .only('is_read', 'subject', 'body') \
        .order_by('-datetime_received')\
        .iterator():
    print('Email subject is:', item.subject)
    print('Email is from:', item.sender)
```

Which yields the following log error:

```
    for item in account.inbox.filter(is_read=False, sender__contains='gmail').only('is_read', 'subject', 'body').order_by('-datetime_received').iterator():
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'iterator'
```

Comment: You mention chunkify but the example code doesn't use it. Was that an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.iterator()` method was deprecated in exchangelib v4.0.0 and finally [removed in v4.7.0](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#470). exchangelib no longer does any internal caching so the method is a no-op.